# Any character with carriage return

Tags: java, regex

New to Regex and I believe I am working on regex for java with one problem that the lines have carriage return in them which makes `(.*)` (the last group) matches everything except new line.

```
^([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s(?:\^\[\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\^\[\[m)\s*([0-9a-fA-F\-]*)\s\(([^\)]+)\)\s((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9$]+):\s(?:\s\-\s)?(.*)
```

Not matching the 2 lines following the first one but picks up the forth one

```
02 Jan 2018 05:25:56,546 ^[[32m[TEXT]^[[m aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
extra line 1
extra line 2
03 Jan 2018 08:25:56,546 ^[[32m[TEXT]^[[m aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
```

Is there a way to have all matched along with carriage return.

**UPDATE:**

Following regex isnt picking up the last group

```
 ^([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s(?:\^\[\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\^\[\[m)\s*([0-9a-fA-F\-]*)\s\(([^\)]+)\)\s((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9$]+):(?:\s\-\s)?(?:(?!^[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(?:\r?\n)?)*

 Service is responding normal
Test results 1 = True
Test results 2 = "{False}"


10 Aug 2018 06:00:02,152 ^[[32m[TEST]^[[m aabb345-397c-4656 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: Service is responding normal
    Test results 1 = True
    Test results 2 = "{False}"
    10 Aug 2018 06:00:02,152 ^[[32m[TEST]^[[m aabb345-397c-4656 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: Service is responding normal
```

https://regex101.com/r/wc529u/2

Comment: The flag "s" will allow dot to match new line, but I think this won't fix your issue if you are trying to match that 4th line.

Comment: If you reply here that you want to match 1st and 4th lines I'll provide a fix to your regex as an answer.

Comment: @Jorge.V The 2nd and 3rd lines should be matched(with 1st line) in the last group  and 4th line should be a separate match all together. 1st and 4th lines are already matching , 2nd and 3rd aren't matching with 1st

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the last `(.*)` with `(?:(?!^[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(?:\r?\n)?)*` as suggested by [Sebastian Proske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836111/sebastian-proske) which uses a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that what follows is not the pattern you specify in your regex and the match any character until the end of the string and match an optional line break.

Explanation of the replaced part

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead

    - `^[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` Pattern that matches the start of the string
    - `).*` Close negative lookahead and match any character zero or more times
  - `(?:\r?\n)?` Match an optional line break
- `)*` Close the non capturing group and repeat zero or more times

Your regex might look like:

[`^([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s(?:\^\[\[[0-9]{2}m)\[([A-Za-z]+)\](?:\^\[\[m)\s*([0-9a-fA-F\-]*)\s\(([^\)]+)\)\s((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9$]+):\s(?:\s\-\s)?(?:(?!^[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(?:\r?\n)?)*`](https://regex101.com/r/wc529u/1/)

Comment: Do you really need a tempered greedy token here? Why not just `(?:(?!^[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(?:\r?\n)?)*` checking the lookahead once per line instead of once per character?

Comment: Wouldn't that miss the first character at the start of the string? The lookahead would succeed starting with the second character. https://regex101.com/r/VIu8ut/1

Comment: This wasn't meant to be the full pattern, just the replacement for your tempered greedy token.

Comment: I see that you mean, like this https://regex101.com/r/wc529u/1 That would indeed be much better! I have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your regex isnt picking up the lines as group
https://regex101.com/r/wc529u/2

Comment: @Fenomatik You could capture the repeating pattern in a capturing group itself https://regex101.com/r/wc529u/3